# FB.login with PHP check

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

my application works like this:

1. User clicks on button and it call "FB.login"
2. After login is page reloaded by "window.location.reload;"
3. I checked in PHP, if user logged in, but it writes that NO
4. I reloaded page once more
5. Now it writes that user is logged

I know that it has something to do with COOKIES. Is there any possible way how to deal with this?? I don't want refresh the page twice.

Thanks for answer,
Zbynek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, using Javascript and everything works

Answer (score 0):

When you are setting a cookie, you cannot read the cookie until after the page refreshes.  You can force a refresh by using php header.

To answer specifically, you cannot read a cookie just written until after you refresh.

Comment: I know this things about cookies, but I thought that window.location.reload is enough

Comment: Are you using firefox?  If so you may try document.location.reload() instead, I think ff has a problem with window.location.reload

Answer (score 0):

You can try: `window.location.reload()` 
Then tell me if it's work?

Comment: It's not working, beacuse I think that I need: First reload: write information to cookie, Second reload: read information from cookie